# Fetch a specific entry through XML by onClick event in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I have a listView containg a list of item(blogs). Each item contain a title and link.
Now i want that when one specific item is click i want to start xml parsing to fetch the content of only that link and show it in another activity.

This is onListItemClick() method which is called when specific item is pressed.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String urlBlog = mainBlogPost.get(position).link;
    Log.d(TAG,urlBlog);
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

This is onPostExecute Method which is displaying the list

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry> results) {
        if (results != null && mException == null) {
            String title,link,summary;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> blogPosts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            for(StackOverflowXmlParser.Entry result : results){
                title = result.title;
                link = result.link;
                summary = result.summary;
                HashMap<String,String> blogPost = new HashMap<String,String>();
                blogPost.put("link",link);
                blogPost.put("title",title);
                //blogPost.put("summary",summary);

                blogPosts.add(blogPost);
            }
            Collections.copy(results,mainBlogPost );   //copying for public access
            String[] keys = {"title","link"};
            int[] ids = {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};
            SimpleAdapter adapter =
                    new SimpleAdapter(MainListActivity.this,blogPosts,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,keys,ids);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        } else {
            if (mException instanceof IOException){
            } else if (mException instanceof XmlPullParserException) {
            }
        }
```

*/  }

```
10-31 14:32:10.612    2616-2616/com.example.talha.appforblog E/MainListActivity﹕ Exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.example.talha.appforblog.MainListActivity.onListItemClick(MainListActivity.java:86)
        at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I want to acheive this.
When a specific item is click, i get the url and get the content of that link through xml parsing..

Comment: Then you should start a http request with a specific link to get response data.

Comment: i am getting error of index out of bound exception when a specific item is clicked. I have pasted my onListItemClick() above

Comment: i have made mainBlogPost list in onPostExecute() method, and copy the "result" list to mainBlogPost list

Comment: Please paste error log here.

Comment: I have pasted it. kindly check above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.copy(results,mainBlogPost );`,I think you want copy results to mainBlogPost,but maybe you misunderstood this method,like here:[http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List, java.util.List)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Collections.html#copy(java.util.List, java.util.List)),the first parameter is destination and the second parameter is source .

Comment: You are right.but there is one problem.
 I cannot set the size of mainBlogPost on its intialization. How can i set its size while copying

Comment: Thank you so much..i have used for loop for copying